# how to set client side variable nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a script that requires client side variables.
However I am having huge issues making this possible.

I am wondering would I use `const`, `var` or `let` for a client side variable.

Comment: All variables are instance-wise. Can you give us at least some code/example whatsover so we can understand, what you're trying to do?

Comment: Please be clearer with your question. If you mean that you are writing JavaScript in a Node.js script and need to store state in the client, this is not directly possible. Your script is executing on the server and has no access to client memory. You will need to write a client-side script and design some kind of API to pass state back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## const

use it as much as possible, you can always use it except when you need to change the value of this variable

## let

use this when you cant use const, you can re-assign a value like this:

```
let age = 7; // declaration
age = 6; // re assignment
```

but keep in mind, u can not redeclare like this:

```
let age = 7; // declartation
let age = 6; // another declaration (will yield error)
```

## var

dont, just dont.... never use var....

Comment: what is the problem with var ? I always use var .

Comment: Var lets you re declare an already existing variable, which can cause people to accidentally make 2 variables with the same name leading to very hard to debug issues. Let only lets you re assign, but once you try to re declare, it will cause an error notifying that you probably did somthing wrong @AnuragShukla